# Price for Revenue Maximization

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> The demand for a product is given by  $p = 9/e^x$ in the domain starting from $x = 0$ and ending at $x = 2$, with $x$ being the amount of the product produced at a price of $p$ dollars each.
>
> At what price will the revenue be maximized?"

I know that the revenue is price*quantity, but I am not sure how I would relate quantity into this equation to calculate the revenue.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should have used $d = 9/e^p$, where $p$ is the price of the product, and $0 \le p \le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Revenue function:
$$R(x)=\frac{9}{e^x}\cdot x$$
Revenue maximization:
$$R'=9\cdot \frac{e^x-xe^x}{e^{2x}}=0 \Rightarrow x=1$$
$$R''(1)=9\cdot \frac{-e}{e^2}<0$$